# Is it possible to use the most recent versions of JQuery, Underscore and Backbone without RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

Until now, I had a compatible combination of libraries **(JQuery, Underscore, Backbone)**. They worked without any problems.
But these versions are pretty old and I want to upgrade to the newer versions. When i replace the libraries, I got some strange errors. I downloaded from all three the newest version, but it didn't worked.
I googled some solutions, but I only found some with "**RequireJS**". But I don't want to reorganize my whole application, so now I'm asking for a way I can do it without "**RequireJS**" or for a simple way to integrate it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Lib Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="backbone-1.1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myotherfiles.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     some code...
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My index.html looks like this but when I run my personal code with it, I get only errors from **underscore** and **backbone**.

One of these errors is:

```
TypeError: n.replace is not a function
in underscore-1.8.3.js
```

**EDIT:**

I found my error. I related to a deprecated method which isn't supported anymore. -.- But I will use **Requirejs** for avoiding further conflicts. My project will enhance a lot and at some point, it will get just too big. I dived a little bit into **Requirejs** and I think its is worth a try.

Comment: did you check which file is giving error, and what underscore function is being called there? might be one of the functions you are using is deprecated..

Comment: You should try the above without your personal code, that way you'll know for sure if the libraries are the source of the error or not.

Comment: I tried to load only the libraries, it worked. I had a deprecated function in my very basic initializing method which I used to test the libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery, Backbone and Underscore are libraries with no external dependencies. They can be used independently from any other javascript code that you write, the only conflict you might encounter is when you define a variable in the global scope with the same name that the ones exported by the libraries in this case "$", "Backbone" and "_".

Require.js is a library that allows you to write modular javascript code, add scripts asynchronously, manage dependencies between them and avoid polluting the global scope but it has not direct relation with any other libraries so it should not cause any problems so the answer is **yes, you can use the libraries without require.js**.

On a personal note I'm not used Backbone but I worked with the others with and without require.js without any problems.

**{Edit}**

Backbone has a hard dependency on underscore.js but still does not relate with require.js and can work independently of it.

Comment: Backbone does need underscore. It may operate without jQuery when used server-side. You can see that for yourself if you look at the [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html).

Comment: Edited. Thaks for the correction. Although question is about the usage of require.js in conjunction with those libraries, not the usage of Backbone itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (without your script obviously) and it doesn't report any error:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Lib Test</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

     console.log('jQuery is',jQuery);
     console.log('underscore is',_);
     console.log('backbone is',Backbone);

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This means the error might be on your script, which is trying to use an underscore method in an unexpected way.